# How to fix "attribute error" when using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I got an error while using pygame library:

> Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member
>
> Module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init'

this is my code

```
import pygame

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()

#create the game screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("space invaders")

# game loop
running = True
while running:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type == pygame.quit:
     running = False
```

Comment: What version of pygame are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive. It has to be `QUIT` rathe rather than `quit`:

<s>`if event.type == pygame.quit:`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Note [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function that uninitialize all pygame modules, but `pygame.QUIT` is the enumeration constant for the *QUIT* event (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)).